# Tomcat - serve static file under different name

Tags: java, html, tomcat, web

In WAR I have a static html page  `MyPage.html`. Since I do not like the URL being `my-page/MyPage.html` I would like to chance it to `my-page/something-else` without changing the  `MyPage.html` name.  How to achieve this?

I tried to  wrap `HttpServletRequest` of `my-page/MyPage.html`  URL  in a wrapper with overriden `getRequestURL()` and `getRequestURI()` but it does not work.

Comment: How about a servlet mapping in web.xml...

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom Servlet filter intercepting calls to /something-else and forwarding (not redirecting) them to the actual MyPage.html URL. You could also make this filter configurable so it can translate any given URL without the browser ever knowing. Still, unless this translation is not an integral functionality of your application, you'd probably be better off simply redirecting in Apache or another web server in front of Tomcat.